# Rails extend has_many collection to include another paramter which modifies the result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, overriding

My invoicing application records multiple payments/invoice.  The problem I'm having is that the customer can pay with cash above what is owing.  So when I view summaries, the cash totals are greater than amounts owing so it's not a realistic view on what I got paid (because I gave change).  So essentially what I want to do is override the payments collection so that if I give it an argument of (true), it will show me all the payments, but any amounts owing back to the customer will be deducted from a cash payment.

**Example 1:**
Invoice totaling $25
Interac Paid: $10
Cash Paid: $20
Change: $5

**Example 2 (with cash-back):**
Invoice totaling $25
Interac Paid: $30
Change: $5

In my Invoice.rb model:

```
has_many :payments, :dependent => :destroy do
    def ???(actual_amounts = false)
        // call to super() ???
        // Find any cash payments and override value to account for change.
        // If there isn't a cash payment, make one.
    end
end
```

---

So these are the results I would expect for both examples:

**Example 1:**
Call to `@invoice.payments` yields $10 and $20 respectively
Call to `@invoice.payments(true)` yields $10 and $15 respectively

**Example 2:**
Call to `@invoice.payments` yields $30
Call to `@invoice.payments(true)` yields $30 Interac and -$5 Cash

Comment: Does it HAVE to be on the `payments` associations? because once you start making your associations return values instead of a `relation` there's no turning back.

Comment: That's a good point. I'll just avoid it altogether.

Comment: Good man. However if you want to edit your question to do something like `def with_surplus` instead I can show you how I might do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made a custom method inside the Invoice model that shows 'return change'. It turns out it didn't make sense to show 'what was essentially paid'...especially when I wanted to compare invoice payments to our payment processor's records.